# Can internet speed be faster than speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light

We send email in order to transfer information and, over time, the technology used to send email improves to send email at faster rate.

Since we use the Internet to send information from one place to another place all over the world, can information speed be faster than light speed via the Internet?

Comment: Plain simple, No.

Comment: obviously **NO**

Comment: In my opinion, this question does not deserve this many downvotes. That most of us can easily answer it, does not mean we should downvote...

Comment: @user3194189 To travel to the other side of the world, would take $0.07s$, maybe it helps you to put the speed of e-mails in perspective.

Comment: Information like emails travel in cables, optic fibers and radio devices. All those things does not send information faster than light, so wouldn't a mix of them.

Comment: It seems people have started down voting easy questions rather than wrong ones and those that do not meet the sites policies.

Comment: @RijulGupta in a way, that is exactly one of the reasons one _should_ downvote a question: when it would have been [easy for the OP to answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778), and they haven't done so.

Comment: @DavidZ : statistically very few people think that nothing can travel faster than light, and as far as I have seen, even many of them have very interesting debates over it. In my view, it can't be possibly easy for a person of significantly less educational level  to get to this answer on their own. The only point to downvote could he that we don't entertain people of so less educational less here.

Comment: @RijulGupta well, whether or not this question deserves a downvote for that reason, I'm saying in general that, whenever e.g. an easy search on Google or Wikipedia would yield the answer to a question and the OP hasn't done that, it is a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: @DavidZ : Can't argue with that reason, I seemed to he treating OP as a toddler.

Comment: '+1' to counter the unjustified downvotes. _"Someone who is new to the subject may find it extremely difficult to research on google etc because they are not familiar with the specific terms and do not know which keyword should they try to search on google."_

Comment: That is a great question. 
Consider that anything faster than the speed of light is likely to break the bound between space and time.

From a comic and exterme perspective, Imagine someone sending an email to himself and receiving it before send it :D

Answer (score 23):

The internet is a collection of physical machines connected by [copper-polyethylene signal wires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_propagation_speed), which carry signals at $0.7c$–$0.8c$, [optical fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber#Index_of_refraction), which carry signals at $0.6c$–$0.7c$, and occasionally radio links, which propagate in air at approximately $c$. Ironically, radio links are generally the slowest way to send *long* messages, because of the way that bandwidth (in [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28signal_processing%29) [senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29) of the word) is allocated. There are also delays introduced when an intermediate machine receives and re-routes a message between two computers.

Internet speed is faster than a lot of things,
[image]
but it's not faster than light.

Answer (score -2):

No, the internet you have is conveyed via radiation, of which the speed is equal to the speed of light, or through wires by moving electrons, whose drift velocity is less than the speed of light. (This is obvious since electrons have mass. According to special relativity mass tends to infinity at light speed. Hence no amount of force can cause acceleration to overcome $v=c$.)

Unless you figure out how to use tachyons for communication. But that is also not possible I suppose, as tachyons don't interact with ordinary matter. And as a direct result, no observation of them is possible, as far as i know.

Comment: Please consider using the normal rules of English writing to make your answer easier to read.

Comment: I don't think your answer is wrong, but it's hard to tell because it's difficult to understand. That's probably why you're getting downvotes; answers are often downvoted if they are unclear, whether or not they are technically correct.

Comment: @Mvs_Physics Just edit your answer and make it simple with proper English, after that you might get some up votes.

Comment: I believe you should mention *propagation speed* or something like that rather than *drift speed*, right? The electron drift velocity is only a few millimeters per second.

Comment: _"drift velocity [..] this is obvious since electrons have mass"_ - the drift velocity is certainly below the speed of light _(in fact it's on the order of meters/hour)_, but that's irrelevant because it's not the electrons themselves carrying the information, but the electric field

Answer (score -2):

I knew the answer.That thought arose in my mind whether internet speed can be faster than speed of light, so i had asked the question.

Within one click your information could reach from one place from another.If a person sends an information from a place 'A' which is far away i.e 300000km from another place 'B', even then information might reach within 1 second.So speed is same as speed of light. So this thought made me to ask such question.

Comment: In point of fact, the speed of the internet is mostly that of optical fiber and coax or twisted pair copper, which is to say about $(2/3)c$. That said, we use a questions and answer format here and "answers" should be reserved for answering the question, not used to explain why you asked it. This has been flagged as "not an answer" and a candidate for deletion. I'm not going to delete it, because you sort of provide an answer, but it is a close thing and I think that right now this is a rather poor answer.