# How fast, based on the laws of physics can the Internet be?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, signal-processing, fiber-optics

Assuming the actual physics, optics, signal processing and similar, how *fast* can we increase the 'speed' of the Internet?

I know the limit would be $$v \le c,$$ but are there some other limits:
optical fiber limits or similar that regulate the maximum speed of the Internet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really a problem in computer engineering and telecoms engineering.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/118514/44126). Your question (v2) confuses questions of latency with questions of bandwidth.

Comment: There is a good physics question here. The speed of light has been one of the limits to computer speed, as lalala says, since 1970 at least. Computers were slower in part because parts were bigger. As parts get smaller, speeds can increase. There are many engineering problems that come with small sizes. E.G. heat dissipation. There can be other limitations. E.G. mechanical hard disks are slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically optical Fibre or RF cable roughly have 70% of the vacuum speed of light. So if you want to ping a server 20000km away it will take at least 200ms there and back. Signal processing etc is extremely fast compared to this time.

For shorter distances sometime people use freespace RF transmission since it is roughly equal the vacuum speed of light. (trading). Here signal processing becomes relevant.

Comment: This answer would be better if you spent a bit of time explaining why optical fiber and coaxial cable transmit signals at some fraction of the speed of light. Just stating a number without citation or explanation is only half an answer in my opinion.